how to move multiple rigs to its right collection?
I have multiple collections with characters but the rigs from the characters are in the wrong collection. The rigs must be in the same collection as the objects it is parented with. How can I move all my rigs to its right collection at once via script? Or is there maybe an addon for that? It needs to be in the same collection

Can you show a screenshot of an example? I usually move the mesh to a separate collection to make it easier to access. The mesh is then still displayed under the armature in the original collection with a parent-child relationship. If you don't want to have the mesh in a separate collection, you would just need to remove it from there, right?
